# Validating entity as a parameter via custom constraint

Tags: java, spring, validation, annotations

Using Spring Boot, I've created an example application.

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import constraint.CheckHelloId;
import dto.HelloDto;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String index(@RequestBody @Valid final HelloDto hello) {
        hello.setId(null);
        validateFromMethodHeader(hello);
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

    private void validateFromMethodHeader(@CheckHelloId final HelloDto helloDto) {
        System.out.println("Validating DTO...");
    }

}
```

I'm trying to add a custom constraint to the DTO HelloDto in the private method that checks if the id field is null or not.

The interface:

```
package constraint;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.METHOD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.PARAMETER;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.Documented;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;

@Target({ FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, TYPE, METHOD, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CheckHelloIdValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface CheckHelloId {

    String message() default "";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

The validator:

```
package constraint;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;
import javax.validation.constraintvalidation.SupportedValidationTarget;
import javax.validation.constraintvalidation.ValidationTarget;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;

import dto.HelloDto;

@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class CheckHelloIdValidator implements ConstraintValidator<CheckHelloId, HelloDto> {

    private static final String ID_VALIDATION_ERROR = "Null or blank ID.";

    @Override
    public void initialize(CheckHelloId arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(HelloDto helloDto, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (StringUtils.isBlank(helloDto.getId())){
            context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();
            context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate(ID_VALIDATION_ERROR).addConstraintViolation();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

The DTO:

```
package dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class HelloDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8792903048191496378L;

    private String id;

    private String message;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

As seen in the private method at the controller, I'm trying to apply the validation of the DTO at a parameter level (I know I can just do it at the index via entity validation, but I want to test this concrete case, that's why I set the id field as null at the controller).

When I run the application and perform the call, the constraint does not apply in the private method, even when the id field is null. Could anybody shed some light on this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To validate consuming json on rest controller beside annotated method parameters `@RequestBody @Valid final HelloDto hello` you have to annotate filed of your json data class with special constraints. For you case it enough to use hibernate validation constraints [@NotNull](http://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/app-server/HibernateAnnotations/api/org/hibernate/validator/NotNull.html) or [@NotEmpty](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/api/org/hibernate/validator/constraints/NotEmpty.html):

```
package dto;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class HelloDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 8792903048191496378L;

    @NotEmpty
    private String id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but even when using hibernate validation constraints, they do not apply when using the custom constraint at a parameter level at the private method. That's the main purpose of my question. Besides, there may be cases where I could want to use other types of attributes apart from strings.

Comment: you can use this hibernate constrains cause its do the same as your custom constraint

Comment: Thanks again. But, as I said in my question: "(I know I can just do it at the index via entity validation, but I want to test this concrete case, that's why I set the id field as null at the controller)."

Comment: `@Valid` triggers all constraint validation annotation on json data class, it knows nothing about your private method. Try to annotate id with `@CheckHelloId `

Comment: I would like to test the uses of the ElementTypes PARAMETER and or METHOD of a custom constraint if possible, that's my main question. The code is just a simple example for setting the enviroment to test it. Appreciate it anyway.